# Keep minimal width of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I need to show such informational box:

[image]

But I want:

1. Keep whole box width minimal as possible (but wrapping actual content)
2. Put it in the left top corner of the activity
3. Numbers should be aligned to right and to the box right border
4. "More" button should be centered horizontally

How can I fix my layout to stisfy the conditions above?

This is my current layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/box_values"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_200">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:text="Param 1:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value1"
            android:text="-464.44"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/title1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier_titles"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title1"
            android:background="@color/teal_700"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title2"
            android:text="P2:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value2"
            android:text="2.1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/title2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier_titles"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title2"
            android:background="@color/teal_700"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier_titles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="2dp"
            app:barrierDirection="end"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="title1,title2"/>

        <Button
            android:text="More"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:flow_horizontalAlign="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider2"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately with your setup it is not possible to achieve what you are trying to do. Use this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/box_values"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple_200"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Param 1:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-464.44"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/teal_700"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="P2:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2.1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/teal_700"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title2" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier_titles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="2dp"
            app:barrierDirection="end"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="title1,title2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="More"
            app:flow_horizontalAlign="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider2" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

If you use this layout everthing depends on the width of the dividers. Because you used them, they divide the layout but even though you configured `wrap_content`, they seem to be taking a lot of space. You could delete them and alter your layout so that you can achieve what you are trying to do.